Modifying mstatus CSR
Running on ESP32-H2 riscv32, building with GCC 14.2, Binutils 14.3.1.
What I want to do is to disable machine interrupts while I do some manipulation of interrupt-related registers, then re-enable them if they were previously. This means (I think) manipulating bit 3 (MIE) of mstatus. The first thing to do is to get the current value of mstatus.
My first approach was csrrci a0, mstatus, 0x8. Before this instruction, mstatus (as determined by gdb> p/x $mstatus) was 0x201888; after it, a0 was 0x201880, while mstatus was unchanged. So the bit had been cleared in the destination register, but not in the CSR.
By way of investigation, I tried csrr a0, mstatus and that also left a0 with bit 3 clear.

My actual code snippet, in Ada (but I hope you can get the gist) -- with the addition of the diagnostic Original_MSTATUS -- is
   Original_MSTATUS : UInt32;
   Saved_MSTATUS : UInt32;
begin
   System.Machine_Code.Asm
     ("csrr %0, mstatus",
      Outputs  => UInt32'Asm_Output ("=r", Original_MSTATUS),
      Volatile => True);
   System.Machine_Code.Asm
     ("csrrc %0, mstatus, 0x8",
      Outputs  => UInt32'Asm_Output ("=r", Saved_MSTATUS),
      Volatile => True);

Now that I think about it, this is called during initialisation, and I'm sure that interrupts aren't enabled - so MSTATUS.MIE should be zero anyway.
On entry, gdb> p/x $mstatus returns 0x201888. After both of the assembly instructions, $mstatus is unchanged, but both the *_MSTATUS variables are 0x201880.
I've tried this with a J-Link EDU adaptor and with Espressif's built-in JTAG interface: same with both adaptors.
The common components are

the Espressif ESP32-H2
openocd (I first used a self-build copy from the Espressif repo, then a built copy from Espressif's IDF; the behaviour I'm interested in was the same, though with the Espressif build the 0x200000 bit wasn't set - to do with the legality of the wfi instruction).


Can you post the code snippet? What you have mentioned doesn't seem like the correct behaviour expected from the mstatus CSR.
